# Having two arrays with similar item, how to remove these items in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question in hand, is to create one new object which properties is setup by copying properties from another object, depending on condition. In fact, they are the value of the same object. To imitate the problem I face, suppose I have the following object:

```
var cars = {car1: ['fast', 'solar energy', 'light', 'fossil energy']};
```

then I want to have property car2, which is an array copying just those string item with 'energy' and remove all these item with 'energy' from car1, how to do it succinctly.

I have tried the following method but it seems a bit complex for me, and please forgive me as I am using angular, but the answer need not be angular:

```
            cars['car2'] = [];
            angular.forEach(cars['car1'], function(value, key) {
                if(cars['car1'][key].indexOf('energy') > -1) {
                    cars['car2'].push(value);
                }
            });
            angular.forEach(cars['car2'], function(value){
                cars['car1'].splice(value);
            });
```

Or Could anyone explain what as the title stated?

Comment: What should be the output ?

Comment: and what have you tried until now?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to explain it better.

Comment: @Weedoze The output should be: cars = {car1: ['fast', 'light'], car2: ['solar energy', 'fosil energy']};

Comment: @winner_joiner Thank you. I have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter()`

```js
var cars = {car1: ['fast', 'solar energy', 'light', 'fossil energy']};
var condition = "energy";
var arr = cars.car1;
cars.car1 = arr.filter(c=>!c.includes(condition));
cars.car2 = arr.filter(c=>c.includes(condition));
console.log(cars);
```

Or with `Array#reduce()`

```js
var cars = {car1: ['fast', 'solar energy', 'light', 'fossil energy']};
var condition = "energy";
var finalObj = cars.car1.reduce((obj,c) => {
  obj.car1 = obj.car1 || [];
  obj.car2 = obj.car2 || [];
  c.includes(condition) ? obj.car2.push(c) : obj.car1.push(c);
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cars = { car1: ['fast', 'solar energy', 'light', 'fossil energy'] };

var express=/\s*energy\s*/g;


var car2=cars.car1.map((e,i)=>{
  return e.replace(express,'')

})

console.log(car2)
//["fast", "solar", "light", "fossil"]
```

Comment: This question has already an accepted answer. Don"t beg for upvotes. If you want to have upvotes, post some good questions or answers and you will naturally get upvotes. You answer has not explanation and it does not provide the output asked by OP

Answer (score -1):

you can use lodash library.using loadash you can achieve that in one line.

```
_.difference([2, 1], [2, 3]);// => [1]


_.differenceBy([2.1, 1.2], [2.3, 3.4], Math.floor);// => [1.2]


var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
_.differenceWith(objects, [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }], _.isEqual);// => [{ 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

You can use any of these methods.For further information check this link -[click here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference)

Comment: This is not using example provided by OP + OP did not ask for lodash